# Implementation of java.util.Map using insertion order as order

Tags: java, dictionary

The JDK documentation on java.util.Map states

> The order of a map is defined as the
>   order in which the iterators on the
>   map's collection views return their
>   elements. Some map implementations,
>   like the TreeMap class, make specific
>   guarantees as to their order; others,
>   like the HashMap  class, do not.

And the documentation on TreeMap states:

> The map is sorted according to the
>   natural ordering of its keys, or by a
>   Comparator provided at map creation
>   time, depending on which constructor
>   is used.

Is there any JDK implementation of Map that uses the order that elements were inserted into the map as the order?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[java.util.LinkedHashMap](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html):

> This implementation differs from `HashMap` in that it maintains a doubly-linked list running through all of its entries. This linked list defines the iteration ordering, which is normally the order in which keys were inserted into the map (*insertion-order*). Note that insertion order is not affected if a key is *re-inserted* into the map.